# Error using \Phalcon\HTTP\ResponseInterface\setJsonContent()

Tags: php, json

I have a REST API, and I am using the setJsonContent() to output (obviously) some json content.

It was working fine until version 1.2.2, but since I'm using version 1.2.4 (and now 1.2.6) it started to eventually show this Warning:
**PHP Warning:  json_encode() [function.json-encode]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument**

It only occur now and then and I don't have a clue of how to track this error. The use of native json_encode() does not dispach the same error for the same data.

I can't track the exact data, since I have a huge database. Is there a way to get the exact byte that is causig this?

Answer (score 1):

Phalcon uses the native `json_encode()` internally (which is confirmed by the warning message) thus you should face the same issue regardless whether you use Phalcon.

What I would suggest is to turn this warning into exception and then in the `catch` block log the data and then examine them.

It would look something like this:

```
function handleError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext)
{
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

// Put this right before the code that produces the warning
set_error_handler('handleError');
try {
    // The code that might trigger the warning
}
catch (ErrorException $e) {
    // Log the data
}

restore_error_handler()
```